# Remove dark borders from autocompletetextview results

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Typing text into the autocompletetextview shows the results with a dark background behind them that has upper and lower padding. I haven't been able to find out where this dark background layout comes from and I would very much like to either get rid of it entirely, or else at least get rid of the upper and lower dark padding. For the autocompletetextview I have a custom adapter that makes use of a layout for each element in the list.. but as far as I know that's the only layout file I'm using for the view.

Here's the code for the autocompletetextview in the toolbar layout:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/search_box"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/auto_complete_background"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_icon"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/search_icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tvTitle"
    android:dropDownSelector="@color/cyan_light"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="-15dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white_semi_transparent"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
    android:popupBackground="@color/white"
    />
```

And here is the code for the layout for each element in the list:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/search_item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:text="@string/placeholder_name"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/search_item_address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/search_item_name"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/search_item_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search_item_name"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/search_item_name"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:text="@string/placeholder_address"
    android:textColor="@color/cyan"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Where is the dark background layout coming from and how can I get rid of it?

UPDATE:

By removing the line of code:

```
android:popupBackground="@color/white"
```

no dark borders. On the other hand, now my results appear on a grey background and I'd like it to be white. Any way I can do this without using popupBackground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be two things:

1) Removing the line:

```
android:popupBackground="@color/white"
```

from the autocompletetextview element

2) Adding the line:

```
android:background="@color/white"
```

to the relativelayout for the result rows

Comment: What if I want to show different edit text kind of background (custom) on AutoCompleteTextView but different in suggestion list?

Comment: doesn't works for me...

Answer (score 0):

There is another more efficient way, by using **android:dropDownSelector** attribute and not setting up **android:popupBackground**.

```
android:dropDownSelector="@android:color/white"
```